# What kind of a sensor does a arcade punch (boxing) machine have?

Tags: load-cell, strain-gage, pressure

I am working on a project, where I have to measure the pressure exerted by a punch. I am trying to understand how an arcade machine works, and see if I could replicate the same mechanism in my project.

Additionally, I would like for the sensor to be in the punch-bag itself, which is different from an arcade machine. (They have the sensor directly on the back of the machine.)

Comment: I'm not sure but, an accelerometer maybe? The higher the punch pressure, the higher the moving speed (thus acceleration for a static object).

Comment: There are a number of ways to do this.  You need to be able to measure the acceleration of the object struck and there is a lot of danger in hitting something that doesn't move, which is probably why the ones I've seen use a pendulum.  As long as you can measure the acceleration to an adequate accuracy, the pendulum formulas are pretty easy to figure out based on the mass of the pendulum, so you can calibrate it initially, but you would need a known striking force to calibrate it with to get real accuracy.

Comment: What kind of acclerometers would they have used in the past though? Haven't arcade boxing machines existed a lot longer than consumer MEMS accelerometers? Would they have really used an accelerometers and not just a spring centered mass connected to what is basically a joystick-like mechanism?

Comment: I know home use body weight balance has 4 HX711 pressure sensors on its four corners. Perhaps we can put say, 20 HX711s inside the bag, and use WiFi controller ESP32 to send report to Tarzan and Mike Tyson https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JvdJ9cfJAfI.

Comment: I don't believe they use MEMS.  Because of the ease of calibration you could use simple position measurement with most of the arcade assemblies and make it more robust to impact than those MEMS modules look to me.  You have to decide how to interpret the acceleration too.  You'll get different acceleration curves with a fast jab compared to a punch with a follow through.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what they use, but I built my own punchbag project for my boxing training. I used an FSR (force sensitive resistor) underneath a few layers of padding. That worked well for me and could work in your project

Comment: A very important point to be considered: the device would be wall-mounted. It cannot move. Thus, I cannot use accelerometers. Suggestion by @MCG seems to be the most applicable.

Comment: @hegemon8 mine was wall mounted too. Worked a treat

Comment: Neat! I have two options to work with: an FSR or a gas-filled interior with a pressure sensor. Can you share some images? Of the device and drawings.

Comment: You could use loadcells, in fact you could probably mount a shipping scale on the wall with some padding and all you would have to do is replace the electronics (for reading at much higher speed).

Answer (score 8):

I do not know how it is done in arcades, but there are several ways of doing this.

- A hollow gas filled interior and a pressure sensor to record the pressure change profile when struck
- An accelerometer (probably the easiest) to record the acceleration profile for a known mass

Comment: Given the fact that the device is intended to be wall-mounted, the gas-filled interior is a good idea. I have to figure out how to stuff the exterior to give it a punch-bag feel.

Comment: The gas cylinder idea is very nice. It also doubles as a dampener!

Answer (score 5):

Well, the really low tech way to do this is to use a seismic mass (i.e. a chunk of iron:D) attached to a spring or a pendulum and some kind of sensor to detect the movement. Since we are literally punching the device you need something sturdy.

You can also use a load cell *if* it's fast enough. Most standard cell are quite slow and may damp the peak.

Really, any way to turn a mechanical movement into a signal can be useful. Accelerometers, even simple potentiometers can do the job. MEMS device as suggested in the comments are game too, but maybe they are too 'refined' for the application.

Answer (score 5):

the real thing is that this boxer machine needs to have a non contact sensor so they can last long, they only have two infrared cross sensors and with this, they calculate the velocity of the pendulum, they have always the same distance between them, so they can have the acceleration and finally, Force = mass * acceleration. They know the mass of the bag and voila, solved with just two infrared LEDs

[machine video fix](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CcbQDYkaThM)

[image: boxer machine sensor]

Answer (score 2):

The problem of measuring force of a punch is more complicated than it seems.

The first challenge is to figure out what variable you are trying to measure. You could measure velocity, acceleration, pressure, impulse, etc.

Pressure is force over area. If I concentrate the force of my body weight into a small area like my top two knuckles and punch something, there will be a large pressure at that point. If the force is spread over 4 knuckles and the front of my fingers, the pressure will be lower since the area is larger. Imagine hitting a single rib with one knuckle or hitting a hard skull with an entire fist. The pressure on both the hand and the target will be very different.

But with respect to boxing, pressure doesn't tell you the entire story. For boxing it is more useful to measure impulse or change of momentum. That will you give a better read of knock out power.

Check out "Fight Like a Physicist: The Incredible Science Behind Martial Arts"
Book by Jason Thalken. This book goes pretty deep into the subject of knockouts.

The machines in arcades usually have a punching bag on hinge. When you punch the bag, the bag accelerates until slams into a hard stop.

There a few ways you could approach this problem. You could measure the change in velocity of the bag and calculate change in momentum. You could measure the acceleration of the bag directly using accelerators. You could use a compressible material and measure the deflection. You could also measure the force exerted on the hard stop by the bag. You could measure force over area to determine pressure. It largely depends on which variable you decide to investigate.

Answer (score 1):

They use a photosensor, which measures the speed of the on and off (sensor)
Why reinvent the wheel?

Answer (score 0):

I would fasten a magnet on the bag lever and measure the velocity and acceleration with a local coil - the voltage is proportional to velocity in first-order (assuming a small displacement) which is plenty good for an arcade game. Only the initial hit is what's important. Not the follow through of the punch.

Optical alternative: Two subsequent light interrupters mounted close together. The first one triggers a timer start. The second one determines how much time has lapsed since timer start. A microcontroller handles the rest.